# mysql search keywords in string table

Tags: mysql, regex, search, words

I have a catID column in product table, it is contain category ids as string,

Something like that '142,156,146,143'

and i Have a query '?catID=156,141,120'

i want to search each id in catID column.

I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE catID REGEXP '156|141|120'
```

this code return products which have any id in catID column , but I want to return products which is have all id,

So , I'am looking for and operator in REGEXP , but I'am couldn't find.

I want to use REGEXP or something like that which function provide to find product with one query , I don't wan to use

```
catID LIKE '156' AND catID LIKE '141' ....
```

if it is posibble.

EDIT : I don't want to perform a function one more time , because the query can be have 100+ id so it's make more harder to write code,

Comment: Is `IN` clause doesn't fulfill the requirement?

Comment: no, IN clause return row which is have any id , I want return row which is have all id.

Comment: So `catID` is not unique in each row?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `find_in_set()` for each category id parameter in order to find the values in set,also if you can alter the schema then do normalize it, by having another junction table which holds the relation from this table to category table

```
select * from 
product 
where 
find_in_set('142',catID ) > 0
```

For multiple values like  `find_in_set('161,168,234,678',preferred_location ) > 0` no it can't be possible doing like this you have to perform for each location id like

```
select * from 
product 
where 
find_in_set('142',catID ) > 0
and find_in_set('156',catID ) > 0
and find_in_set('146',catID ) > 0
and find_in_set('143',catID ) > 0 ... for more
```

[**Database normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

[**find_in_set**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

### Sample Schema

Table

- Products (id,other columns)
- Categories (id,other columns)
- Product_categories (id,product_id,category_id)

Product_categories  is a junction table which will hold product_id and one category_id per each product so each will have a relation with single category and single product at a time

For example

Products

```
id  name

1  product 1
2  product 2
```

Categories

```
id  name

142  category 1
156  category 2
146  category 3
143  category 4
```

Product_categories

```
id  product_id  category_id
1     1          142  
2     1          156  
3     1          146  
4     1          143
```

Now you can join these tables and query like below using in() and count should be equal to the no of category ids provided as parameter

```
select p.* from
Products p
join Product_categories pc on (p.id = pc.product_id)
where pc.category_id in(142,156,146,143)
group by p.id
having count(distinct pc.category_id) = 4
```

### [`Sample Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f29e4/1)

or if you can't count the provided category ids as parameter you can do this by following query

```
select p.* from
Products p
join Product_categories pc on (p.id = pc.product_id)
where pc.category_id in(142,156,146,143)
group by p.id
having count(distinct pc.category_id) = 
ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH('142,156,146,143')
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( '142,156,146,143', ",", "") ) 
        ) / LENGTH(",")        
    ) + 1
```

### [`Sample Demo 2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f29e4/3)

Comment: yes , I know I can do this with multiple perform IN or find_in_set() function  , But I want to do this with just one time perform , if it is possible.Is there a any other way REGEXP or something like that ?

Comment: @sanchez23 yes there are other ways if you properly organize your structure by apply some normalization to it if you can't alter your schema then i guess no there will no other way to that or if so then it will be very complicated by user user defined functions or something other

Comment: yes I can normalize this database , do you have suggestion or example , how can I normalize this database ?

Comment: @sanchez23 see my updated answer hope it makes sense